# Non-stoichiometric equations using chemformula (chemmacros)

Tags: chemmacros, chemformula

Upon trying to do this non-stoichiometric reaction using chemmacros;

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{chemmacros} 
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\usepackage{chemgreek}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document} 
\begin{equation}
\ch{Mg1.8Fe0.2SiO4\sld{} + 1.37 H2O -> 0.5 Mg3Si2O5(OH)4\sld{} + 0.3 Mg(OH)2\sld{} + 0.067 Fe3O4\sld{} + 0.067 H2\gas{}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I get something like this. See the formatting errors in the stiochiometry term.

[image: See error in stoichiometries]

Any help help would super duper!!

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly. Obviously the equation is too long, so you'd be better off with something like `\begin{multline}
\ch{Mg1.8Fe0.2SiO4\sld{} + 1.37 H2O -> 0.5 Mg3Si2O5(OH)4\sld{} \\ {+} 0.3 Mg(OH)2\sld{} + 0.067 Fe3O4\sld{} + 0.067 H2\gas{}}
\end{multline}`, but is that what you meant?

Comment: You probably want `\ch{Mg_{1.8}Fe_{0.2}SiO4}`

Comment: Thanks Torbjorn and clemens for your answers. Clemens agreed that was the path I was think about going down but wondered if I was missing some chemmacros trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to denote the decimal subscripts as such:

```
Mg_{1.8}Fe_{0.2}SiO4
```

As a further suggestion you might want to break the long equation into two lines:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
  \ch{Mg_{1.8}Fe_{0.2}SiO4\sld{} + 1.37 H2O -> 0.5 Mg3Si2O5(OH)4\sld{}} \\
  \ch{+ 0.3 Mg(OH)2\sld{} + 0.067 Fe3O4\sld{} + 0.067 H2\gas{}}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]