How to implement a multiline split when using chemmacros, chemformula & chemfig with LuaLaTeX
I've explored how to use \begin{split} and \begin{multline} to break the following long equation when using \ch. None have worked. I've assembled a not-so-short (apologies) MWE that will compile as is, with the newline "\ \ " commented out.
Uncommenting the newline "\ \ " when using \begin{split} results in an error message: "Cannot use `split' here".
When using \begin{multline} the error message is: "Package amsmath Error: \begin{multline} allowed only in paragraph mode."
% Source: How do you write the names under the chemicals?
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667122/how-do-you-write-the-names-under-the-chemicals/670042?r=SearchResults&c2c23zz27ewefznk3k3iai7jgu=CgEhyzYICgXIveKyQGtOq7iA7ddDpGrOl0HbVCHfQa2pswYCD9jqFhP6XkZ7MNmPuiknoU1P#670042

\documentclass[landscape]{article} 
% \usepackage{amsmath} 
\newcommand{\bmmax}{1} 
\newcommand{\hmmax}{0}
\usepackage{bm}
% \usepackage{chemformula} 
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % (a superset of the amsmath package)
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[%
    anchorcolor=blue,%
    citecolor=blue,%
    filecolor=blue,%
    linkcolor=blue,%
    urlcolor=blue,%
    breaklinks=true,%
    bookmarks=true,%
    colorlinks=true,%
    hyperindex=true,%
    pageanchor=true,%
    pdfencoding=auto,%      % Added 02/09/ 2021 for ‘Mind Map’
    pdfpagelabels=true,%
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,%
    unicode=true%
]{hyperref}

\newlength{\oldfboxsep}
\setlength{\oldfboxsep}{\fboxsep}

\definecolor{cssgreen}{RGB}{0,128,0} 
\newcommand{\txc}[2]{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}

% Define the \noteworthy command 
\newrobustcmd*{\noteworthy}[3][-3mm]{
\vspace{-5mm}
\setlength{\oldfboxsep}{\fboxsep}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt} % \fboxsep: the distance between the frame and the content.
\begin{samepage}%
\begin{center}%
\begin{equation}\boxed{#2}\vspace{#1}\end{equation}%
\nopagebreak%
\small\itshape{#3}\normalsize%
\end{center}%
\end{samepage}\medskip      % \medskip=6pt±2pt vspace*{7mm}
\justifying 
\setlength{\fboxsep}{\oldfboxsep}%
}

\usepackage[left=0.5cm,top=2cm,text={26cm,17cm}]{geometry}

\begin{document}

% Equation 9
\vspace{0.4cm}
\refstepcounter{reaction}\usetagform{reaction}\setstretch{0.7}  % Spaces (and ‘ ‘) are important in: chemformula. 
{ \bfseries
\noteworthy[+15mm]{% 
% \begin{multline}  % [1]
\begin{split}   % [2]
\chemnameinit{\ch{ATPNADPH}}%
\schemestart%
\chemname{\ch{3 CO2\gas{}}}{\scriptsize carbon \\{\scriptsize dioxide}} \+{1ex,1ex,}%
\chemname{\ch{9 ATP}}{\scriptsize adenosine \\{\scriptsize triphosphate}} \+{1ex,1ex,}%
\chemname{\ch{6 NADPH}}{\scriptsize reduced~form \\{\scriptsize of~NADP\pch}} \+{1ex,1ex,}%
\chemname{\ch{6 H\pch }}{\scriptsize hydrogen}%
\ch{ -> }%
% \\    % <== Code runs so long as newline is commented out. 
\chemname{\ch{3 H2O\lqd{}}}{\scriptsize water} \+{1ex,1ex,}%
\chemname{\ch{C3H6O3\textnormal{-}phosphate }}{\scriptsize D-glyceraldehyde \\{\scriptsize 3-phosphate (G3P)}} \+{1ex,1ex,}%
\chemname{\ch{9 ADP}}{\scriptsize Adenosine \\{\scriptsize diphosphate}} \+{1ex,1ex,}%
\chemname{\ch{8 P_i}}{\scriptsize Phosphate \\{\scriptsize ions}} \+{1ex,1ex,}%
\chemname{\ch{6 NADP\pch }}{\scriptsize Nicotinamide~adenine \\{\scriptsize dinucleotide~phosphate}}%
\schemestop%
\chemnameinit{}%
\end{split}
% \end{multline}
 } {\nopagebreak \vspace{-3mm}Overall equation for the \txc{cssmaroon}{\emph{light}-\textbf{\myuline{in}}\:\!\emph{dependent}} reactions in green plants.\vspace{+3mm} }
\emph{\normalfont }} \par
\normalfont }
\setstretch{1.0}

% [1] Non-stoichiometric equations using chemformula (chemmacros), https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388159/non-stoichiometric-equations-using-chemformula-chemmacros
% [2] Line break in chemmacros, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376268/line-break-in-chemmacros/376269?iw6bvsedctuttslahspc7u5g6m=W6UQgfREj2ONSLsJWyfLAjIeUnVPwsh5GYEAP6zkAE55TU3PeMAiL7r8BmR1ryTBdVqx6ylY#376269

\end{document}


Any thoughts on how to create a multiline split with the above \ch{} code MWE would be greatly appreciated!

The one answer provided did not offer a solution that included a box around the wide equation, as needed in this particular instance.
Instead, I opted to resize the wide equation to fit within the width of a standard page using a judicious application of the \hspace command. Thus, no split was required. The resulting equation MWE follows:
% Source: How do you write the names under the chemicals?
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667122/how-do-you-write-the-names-under-the-chemicals/670042?r=SearchResults&c2c23zz27ewefznk3k3iai7jgu=CgEhyzYICgXIveKyQGtOq7iA7ddDpGrOl0HbVCHfQa2pswYCD9jqFhP6XkZ7MNmPuiknoU1P#670042

% \documentclass[landscape]{article} 
\documentclass{article} 
% \usepackage{amsmath} 
\newcommand{\bmmax}{1} 
\newcommand{\hmmax}{0}
\usepackage{bm}
% \usepackage{chemformula} 
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % (a superset of the amsmath package)
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[%
    anchorcolor=blue,%
    citecolor=blue,%
    filecolor=blue,%
    linkcolor=blue,%
    urlcolor=blue,%
    breaklinks=true,%
    bookmarks=true,%
    colorlinks=true,%
    hyperindex=true,%
    pageanchor=true,%
    pdfencoding=auto,%      % Added 02/09/ 2021 for ‘Mind Map’
    pdfpagelabels=true,%
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,%
    unicode=true%
]{hyperref}

\newlength{\oldfboxsep}
\setlength{\oldfboxsep}{\fboxsep}

\definecolor{cssgreen}{RGB}{0,128,0} 
\definecolor{cssmaroon}{RGB}{128,0,0} 
\newcommand{\txc}[2]{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}

% Define the \noteworthy command 
\newrobustcmd*{\noteworthy}[3][-3mm]{
\vspace{-5mm}
\setlength{\oldfboxsep}{\fboxsep}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt} % \fboxsep: the distance between the frame and the content.
\begin{samepage}%
\begin{center}%
\begin{equation}\boxed{#2}\vspace{#1}\end{equation}%
\nopagebreak%
\small\itshape{#3}\normalsize%
\end{center}%
\end{samepage}\medskip      % \medskip=6pt±2pt vspace*{7mm}
\justifying 
\setlength{\fboxsep}{\oldfboxsep}%
}

% \usepackage[left=0.5cm,top=2cm,text={26cm,17cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,top=2cm,text={17cm, 26cm}]{geometry}

\begin{document}

% Equation 9
\setstretch{0.6}
{ \bfseries
\noteworthy[+1mm]{%
% \begin{split}
\chemnameinit{\ch{ATPNADPH}}%
\schemestart%
\chemname{\ch{3 CO2\gas{}}}{\scriptsize carbon \\{\scriptsize dioxide}} \hspace{-3mm} \+{1ex,1ex,} \hspace{-2mm}%
\chemname{\ch{9 ATP}}{\scriptsize adenosine \\{\scriptsize triphosphate}} \hspace{-3mm} \+{1ex,1ex,} \hspace{-2mm}%
\chemname{\ch{6 NADPH}}{\scriptsize reduced~form \\{\scriptsize of NADP\pch}} \hspace{-3mm} \+{1ex,1ex,} \hspace{-2mm}%
\chemname{\ch{6 H\pch }}{\scriptsize hydrogen} \hspace{-2mm}%
\textcolor{cssmaroon}{\ch{->}}%     % \\
\chemname{\ch{3 H2O\lqd{}}}{\scriptsize water} \hspace{-3mm} \+{1ex,1ex,} \hspace{-2mm}%
\chemname{\ch{C3H6O3\textnormal{-}phosphate }}{\scriptsize D-glyceraldehyde \\{\scriptsize 3-phosphate (G3P)}} \hspace{-3mm} \+{1ex,1ex,} \hspace{-2mm}%
\chemname{\ch{9 ADP}}{\scriptsize Adenosine \\{\scriptsize diphosphate}} \hspace{-2mm} \+{1ex,1ex,} \hspace{-1mm}%
\chemname{\ch{8 P_i}}{\scriptsize Phosphate \\{\scriptsize ions}} \hspace{-3mm} \+{1ex,1ex,} \hspace{-1mm}%
\chemname{\ch{6 NADP\pch }}{\scriptsize Nicotinamide \\{\scriptsize adenine} \\{\scriptsize dinucleotide} \\{\scriptsize phosphate}} \hspace{-2mm}%
\schemestop%
\chemnameinit{}%
% \end{split}
 } {\nopagebreak \vspace{-3mm}Overall equation for the \txc{cssmaroon}{light-in\:\!dependent} reactions in green plants.\vspace{+3mm} } \par
\normalfont }
\setstretch{1.0}

\end{document}

An image of the resulting chemical equation is:

Tight, but it fits. Boxed as required for my particular application.
Thanks for reading.

Using ChemFig:
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}    
\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig{3 CO_2}}{carbon \\dioxide} \+ \chemname{\chemfig{9 ATP}}{adenosine \\triphosfate} \+ \chemname{\chemfig{6 NADPH}}{reduced form \\of NADP$^{+}$} \+ \chemname{\chemfig{6 @{a}H^{+}}}{hydrogen} \arrow(@{a}--){->}
%
\arrow(@{a}--){}[270,1.2,,,,draw=none]
%
\chemname{\chemfig{3 H_2O_{(l)}}}{water} \+ \chemname{\chemfig{C_3H_6O_3-phosfate}}{D-glyceraldehyde \\3-phosphate (G3P)} \+  \chemname{\chemfig{9 ADP}}{adnosine \\diphosfate} \+ \chemname{\chemfig{8 P_i}}{phosphate\\ions}
\hspace{.5cm} \+ \hspace{.5cm} \chemname{\chemfig{6 NADP^{+}}}{Nicotinamide adenine\\dinucleotide phosphate}
\schemestop
\end{document}


To build the box around the reaction, I find it easiest to use the tcolorbox package
